# Magento Fatal error : bad way to acess getModelInstance() method

Tags: php, magento, apache, mage

I have already installed Magento on my server but this time, with the same process, I have an error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a
>   non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php on line 462

I call this process with "localhost"(redirect to */var/www/html/magento*) but I have the same error if a go throught a virtualhost like "testmagento.com" for example .

I work on

> fedora 15,  httpd,  mysql 5.5.24,  php 5.3.14.

How I can resolve it ?

Regards,

-- 
Thomas 
(French)

Comment: Which Magento version do you use?

Comment: magento-1.7.0.1 , You have an idea ?

Comment: No idea yet, missing core details in your question (e.g. _when exactly_ does this happen?). But having the version number is always helpful when trying to solve programming issues.

Comment: It's happen when I try to install Magento, when I call localhost to go to installation page of magento.

I specify that all my files and folder are in 777 chmod.

Comment: FYI Don't use 'localhost'. Use 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found that The following files and folders need their permissions set to the number ‘777’, so that Magento can save data properly:

```
/var/.htaccess
/app/etc
/var
```

Answer (score 1):

From magento root directory run this as single command:

chmod 777 app/etc; chmod -R 777 var; chmod -R 777 media

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the Magento Framework first:

/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::init($mageRunCode, $mageRunType, array());